# How might a List<T> be reset?

Tags: c#

I have an object I create and stick in a collection:

```
public class Level
{
    private string id;

    private List<LevelTypes> usableLevelTypes;  // LevelTypes is an enum
    private List<BlockTypes> levelMapping;      // BlockTypes is also an enum

    public Level(string id, List<LevelTypes> levelTypes, List<BlockTypes> incomingBlocks)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.usableLevelTypes = levelTypes

        levelMapping = incomingBlocks;
    }
```

Stepping through this, I can see each item being set properly.  The object is then placed in a HashSet.

Another class then iterates through the HashSet calling each item's overloaded `.ToString()` method.

At this point I have all relevant variables in this class on my watch list.  Everything within the object called is set properly. "id", "levelMapping" and all other variables that I have not listed including other `List<T>`'s and int's contain their proper values except "usableLevelTypes", which is reported as being empty.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    var s = new StringBuilder();

    s.Append("ID: " + id);
    s.Append(" Level Types: " + usableLevelTypes[0].ToString()); // At this point,
    // this list should have at minimum one value in it.  However, it is empty and
    // will throw an exception stating as much.

    return s.ToString();
}
```

At no point is `.Clear()` called on the usableLevelTypes List and it is read-only.  How could it be reset when other lists within the same object are not?

Comment: The params you pass in seem to match. levelTypes doesn't exist in your example and you are assigning it to the field this.usableLevelTypes. Is this a typo?

Comment: It was a typo. Original code is correct in that aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating a copy of the list that you pass in to the `Level` constructor for `usableLevelTypes`. So whatever is happening to that outer list is going to happen to the list inside `Level`. Without seeing the calling code, I cannot tell you specifically what the problem is.

Comment: try this... it should disappear if siride's assertion is correct ( which I think it is ) this.usableLevelTypes = new List<LevelTypes>(usableLevelTypes);

Comment: If you were using the list in a loop, it's possible it could have been reset there. Anyway, just be careful not to unintentionally capture references when loading objects into other objects.